# Data does not appear in stacked area plot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a stacked area plot, however my ggplot only display axis and not the plotted data, as shown in the picture. I am not sure what why it does not display any of the data, the code seemed pretty straight forward. I am not getting any error messages either.

```
stack20 <- ggplot(DF1, aes(x= date, y= number_reports, fill=nuisancelevel)) + 
  geom_area(position="stack") + theme_classic() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Reds") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
stack20
```

See below the dput for my code, I have included the first 10 rows.

```
structure(list(date = c("2020-07-01", "2020-07-01", "2020-07-02", 
"2020-07-03", "2020-07-05", "2020-07-05", "2020-07-05", "2020-07-06", 
"2020-07-06", "2020-07-06"), nuisancelevel = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("Geen overlast", 
"Een beetje overlast", "Veel overlast", "Heel veel overlast"), class = "factor"), 
    number_reports = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
    )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(date = c("2020-07-01", 
"2020-07-01", "2020-07-02", "2020-07-03", "2020-07-05", "2020-07-05", 
"2020-07-05", "2020-07-06", "2020-07-06", "2020-07-06"), nuisancelevel = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("Geen overlast", 
"Een beetje overlast", "Veel overlast", "Heel veel overlast"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .drop = TRUE))
``

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/05hvb.jpg
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Hi  yes of course! I have never used dput(), so I hope I am doing it correctly (I think so reading other posts). Here is the first ten rows of my data. But please let me know if I made a mistake!

dput(snippet, "snippet.txt")
dget("snippet.txt")

Comment: Hi @TijmenH, you should copy the output of `dput(DF1)` in your console and paste that into your question above.

Comment: Hi @Quinten, thanks for clarifying. I have added the dput. In addition I have gotten some warnings when trying to plot again. But I couldn't find a proper explanation in a similar situation 

Warning messages:
1: In max(ids, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In max(ids, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: `geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")` works if a stacked bar chart is an alternative  for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit tricky, but you could change your dates to date format and use `rank` to plot them like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
DF1$date <- as.Date(DF1$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
stack20 <- ggplot(DF1, aes(x= rank(date), y= number_reports, fill=nuisancelevel)) + 
  geom_area(position = "stack") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = rank(DF1$date),labels = format(DF1$date, "%Y-%m-%d")) +
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Reds") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
stack20
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Amazing this did the trick, thanks @Quinten! 
I have applied it to my entire dataset and the data appeared, using as.Date(DF1$date) also took care of the data being displayed chronologically on the x-axis

Comment: @TijmenH, Dat is mooi! Glad it helped you. Always important to check what data structure is necessary like types of columns in this case date.

Comment: yes that is definitely a must for next time. I however expected the data to appear but not in a chronological order. Interesting how it turned out completely empty though